# Make install kernel module without reboot?

Tags: linux, reboot, make, kernel-module

I am trying to make changes to a buggy driver on Linux (mint).
Is it possible to make and test the changes without rebooting every time?

Comment: What driver is it? The real key is if the module is actually a (un)loadable module. If it's compiled in to your kernel, there still may be a way as I think I saw a somewhat recent new kernel feature for handing off control to another kernel while running (though that sounds crazy). Hennes has a good reply below.

Comment: I actually used kernel modules when I was writing a Firewire driver for the Linux kernel (Not the one in the kernel, just one used only in Natlab). One thing I learned the hard way: Keep your backups (code) on another host than the host you are testing on. (in indsight: that *should* have been obvious).

Answer (score 2):

If you put your changes in a module rather than inside a monolithic kernel then you can load and unload the module.

See:

- Modprobe (and `man 8 modprobe`)
- lsmod, insmodm rmmod
- The [Linux loadable kernel module HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/)